# Auto waiting and next video like Youtube using Javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, autoplay

I want to create an function auto next after x second like YouTube using JavaScript or JavaScript library. Can anyone has suggest for me? Many thanks.

Comment: I have a list video, and I want when finish each video, player wait and next to the next one. I code video player using HTML5 and javascript

Comment: You can use the `ended` event ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)) to define actions you want to do when the actual video finish. More that that, it's better to post your code if you have it.